# SQLLite dialect for Hibernate, Table not mapped error

Tags: java, hibernate, sqlite

I'm currently developing an app in JavaFX and I'm using an SQLLite database with the sqlite-jdbc-3.8.11.2 connector, plus for my ORM model I choose the latest Hibernate distribution. The problem I'm getting is that I can't execute queries written by me, despite I successfully managed to Insert, Read, Update and Delete from the database, I can't do it without using the default operations from Hibernate.
These are my configuration settings in the hibernate.cfg.xml file:

```
<!-- JDBC Database Connection Settings-->      
        <property name="connection.driver_class">org.sqlite.JDBC</property>
        <property name="connection.url">jdbc:sqlite:database.db</property>
        <!-- JDBC Connection Pool Settings-->
        <property name="connection.pool_size">1</property>
        <!-- Selecting SQL Dialect-->
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect</property>
        <!-- Echo the SQL to stdout-->
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>
        <!-- Set the current session context -->
        <property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>
```

As you can see, I'm using HSQL Dialect for this database, this is because I can't find a sqlite dialect in the package provided by Hibernate framework. However, as I said before, it works somehow.

So I have a class named Program which is actually a table in the database called Programs. Here is the definition of Program in Java code:

```
public class Program {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "program_id")
    protected int program_id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    protected String name;
    @Column(name = "developer")
    protected String developer;
    @Column(name = "rating")
    protected int rating;
    @Column(name = "state")
    protected int state;
    @Column(name = "reservation_date")
    protected String reservedDate;
    @Column(name = "sent_date")
    protected String sentDate;

    public Program() {
    }

    public Program(String name, int state, LocalDate reservation_date) {
        this.name = name;
        this.state = state;
        this.reservedDate = reservation_date.toString();
    }
```

Now I have another class named DatabaseConnector which I use to manage database connections. Here is its code:

```
public class DatabaseConnector {
    private final SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    public DatabaseConnector() {
        sessionFactory = new Configuration()
                .configure()
                .addAnnotatedClass(Program.class)//adding table
                .buildSessionFactory();
    }

    public Program getProgram(int id) {
        Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        session.beginTransaction();
        Program p = session.get(Program.class, id);//captures an object from the database
        session.getTransaction().commit();
        return program;
    }
```

As you can see up above there is a getProgram() method which works perfectly.

However, when I try to execute my own query, based on the Hibernate documentation, it should be this way:

```
public Program getProgram(int id) {
        Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        session.beginTransaction();
        List<Program> p = session.createQuery("FROM Programs WHERE   Programs.id="+id).list();//This should find an Program
        session.getTransaction().commit();
        return p.get(0);
    }
```

This is the error Hibernate shows:

```
  java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: Programs is not mapped [FROM Programs WHERE Programs.id=1]
```

I must say that this error is not only happening for SELECT operations but every operation I try to execute with my own personal Query. I believe this mistake is related with the database dialect, but I'm not quite sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see any reason to believe this is related to the dialect. Your HQL is not correct. Your query should be

```
"FROM Program p WHERE   p.id="+id
```

(Note `Program`, the class name, not `Programs`, the table name.)

Better still, use parameters in the query:

```
List<Program> p = session.createQuery("FROM Program p WHERE p.id=:id")
         .setParameter("id", id)
         .list();
```

Or, since your are selecting by a field called `id`, you are presumably expecting a single result in the list:

```
 Program p = session.createQuery("FROM Program p WHERE p.id=:id")
         .setParameter("id", id)
         .uniqueResult();
```

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you should fix is the dialect. There are different solutions to be found in the web. I would try this one:

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>net.kemitix</groupId>
   <artifactId>sqlite-dialect</artifactId>
   <version>0.1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

The depedency contains `org.hibernate.dialect.SQLiteDialect` which looks very reasonable. But I didn't test it myself.
Would be interesting to hear how it worked out!